# При обучении логистической регрессией ошибка декодирования: откуда?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, регрессия

Пытаюсь построить модель классификации цифр датасета mnist. Ловлю ошибку на этапе обучения модели LogisticRegression:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

С чем это может быть связано?

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


train = np.loadtxt('/kaggle/input/digit-recognizer/train.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
test = np.loadtxt('/kaggle/input/digit-recognizer/test.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

train_label = train[:, 0]  # В нулевом столбце представлены конкретные цифры

scaler = StandardScaler()
train_img = scaler.fit_transform(train[:, 1:])
test_img = scaler.fit_transform(test[:, 1:])

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(train_img)
pca.fit(test_img)

logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
logisticRegr.fit(train_img, train_label)
```

Answer (score 1):

Этот баг - прикол lbfgs. Возможно, в новых версиях это уже исправили, но всё-таки попробуйте прописать в терминале

```
pip install scikit-learn  -U
```

Это обновит scikit-learn, если существует такая необходимость.
Также стоит поменять решатель, если вам это не принципиально. На acc это сильно не скажется, но вот проблему решит.

```
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear')
```